# ISAPI_REWRITE a simple search and replace?

Tags: isapi-rewrite

Using ISAPI REWRITE v3

I need to replace a string in an URL.  The old string is 'p=type1_' and the new is 'p=type2_'.  So

```
http://www.somesite.com/cgi-bin/script.pl?t=something&p=type1_abcde
```

becomes

```
http://www.somesite.com/cgi-bin/script.pl?t=something&p=type2_abcde
```

I reckon this should work:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)p=type1_(.*)$ $1p=type2_$2  [NC]
```

But I get a 'Pattern Not Matched' in the ISAPI_REWRITE RegexTest app as soon as the original string contains a '?' - which, in practice, it always would.

How do I do this simple search and replace?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}` to search the querystring.

Try something like this:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} t=(.*)&p=type1_(.*)
RewriteRule ^cgi-bin/script.pl$ cgi-bin/script.pl?t=$1&p=type2_$2 [NC]
```